# How does the derived class occupy the space of base class in C++

Tags: c++

Case 1:

```
class A {
 private:
  uint32_t a1 : 8;
};

class B : public A {
 private:
  uint32_t a2 : 2;
  uint32_t a3 : 22;
};
```

size(B) prints 4 Bytes

Case 2:

```
class A {
 private:
  uint32_t a1 : 8;
  uint32_t a2 : 2;
};

class B : public A {
 private:
  uint32_t a3 : 22;
};
```

size(B) prints 8 Bytes

So Why these two cases corresponding to 2 different results?

Comment: Compiler can do as it wants here. For specific reasons, gotta know which compiler you used, and ask the developers of that compiler why they chose to do it that way.

Comment: size(B) ? I suppose you mean `sizeof(B)`. Which compiler are you using? Generally `sizeof(T)` is implementation defined

Comment: the reason is most likely alignment and padding. `B` isnt just all members in one class, but it has a `A` subobject

Comment: Printing `sizeof(A)` along with `sizeof(B)` would be interesting and helpful in understanding the issue.

Answer (score 1):

> So Why these two cases corresponding to 2 different results?

Because the compiler is allowed to place struct/class members at any offset it sees fit, as long as the order of members is preserved. And while it's somewhat "predictable" how things are padded and where they end up for "normal" types, any notion of "rules of thumb" go out of the window as soon as bitfields and inheritance are mixed.